# Python on Jar - Running python Script after process end in Java

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, processbuilder, runtime.exec

I want to run a python script(tensorflow's Image label script) after RPi's camera module captures a photo using a jar file. I have tried both Runtime and ProcessBuilder, but it says no file or Directory found.

Here's my Code for the Runtime Code:

```
    Process rt = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 -m scripts.image-label.py");
    rt.waitFor();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rt.getInputStream()));
    String read = in.readLine();
    ML = read;
    result resfin = new result();
    resfin.setVisible(true);
```

And here's the code for my ProcessBuilder one:

```
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/home/pi/Desktop/ML/scripts/image-label.py");
    Process np = builder.start();
    np.waitFor();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(np.getInputStream()));
    String read = in.readLine();
    ML = read;
    result resfin = new result();
    resfin.setVisible(true);
```

Am i doing something wrong? Or am i missing something? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: change to `ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("python3","/home/pi/Desktop/ML/scripts/image-label.py");` should work. Let me know if this works, will add as answer

Comment: Will do! Trying this right now. One question though, where do i put the -m? 

Will it be like ProcessBuilder("python3 -m","*directory") or would it be like ProcessBuilder("python3","-m","*directory*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with the following code, it is working fine, though I have not tried with -m "module" flag, since I do not know how to create a module file in python.
Found some of the issues with code:
1. You need to pass python3 as an argument to process builder as shown below
2. Provide an absolute path for a python file.
3. You can use either of Runtime or ProcessBuilder without an issue.

```
//        Process rt = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 -m /Users/<user-name>/demo/JavaNotepad/src/main/java/com/mypython.py");
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("python3", "-m", "/Users/<user-name>/demo/JavaNotepad/src/main/java/com/mypython.py");
        Process rt = builder.start();
        int exitCode = rt.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exited with : " + exitCode);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rt.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rt.getErrorStream()));

    System.out.println("Python file output:");
    String line;
    BufferedReader reader;
    if (exitCode != 0) {
        reader = err;
    } else {
        reader = in;
    }
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! I figured out that i really don't need to run it as a module. i just removed the -m and it works like a charm. Thank you!